# Windows XP Pro Update KB2707511 installing over and over

Tags: windows-update, windows-xp

I am having a very peculiar issue installing Windows Updates on Windows XP Pro SP3. This is installed on a Virtual Machine (Oracle VirtualBox) with VM guest tools installed. I'm trying to get it up to date, but the update KB2707511 keeps repeatedly installing. It installs in a matter of about 5 seconds, then completes successfully. 20 seconds later, there's another update ready for the exact same one. I've tried restarting the machine and running both auto updates and updates from within the browser. The same one just keeps appearing.

What is this issue coming from? How do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what have you've actually tried, honestly.  (Assuming you've tried more than just trying to install it over and over, at least.)

Check the event logs for any errors or warnings related to the install, try uninstalling it completely and letting in install again, and if that doesn't work, [there's an MS KB article on this issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339) (which has different resolutions for the different causes of this behavior).